# Different languages are not working after creating setup file

Tags: c#, winforms, installation

I created C# windows form project. My app has 2 languages (for now) and the user can switch between them. The program works correctly in debug mode; the language changes and the related form is shown. When I create a setup file even after the language change, the language of the form is not changing. Why is this happening?

This is my program file code:

```cs
static void Main()
{
    if (Properties.Settings.Default.languages == "Farsi")
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("fa-IR");
    }
    else if (Properties.Settings.Default.languages == "English")
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
    }
    
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(true);
    Application.Run(new SplashScreenForm());
}
```

Comment: You did include the localized xxx.resources.dll in your setup?

Comment: i only add the primary output. how can all resources.dll to setup file?

Comment: i checked all of the check box for test and problem solved. i now should test for find witch one solved the problem. before i always add only primery output. thank you for your help.